# Is it possible to have multiple subdomain levels with DNS and Nginx?

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, subdomain

This seems like a simple question, but after some Google searching I can't seem to find the answer.

I have a staging server where I would like to mimic the production server as much as possible. Let's say I own `example.com` and I decide that I want to host a blog using `blog.example.com`. I would like to be able to stage the blog before I push it to production using the staging address `blog.stage.example.com`. I rather do this than buy another domain such as `stage-example.com` or use naming conventions like `blog-stage.example.com`.

Obviously, I would want `blog.stage.example.com` to point to the server running on the staging environment (e.g. IP 1.1.1.1), and `blog.example.com` to point to the server running on the production environment (e.g. IP 2.2.2.2).

I am using Nginx for my web back-end and have Gandi as a hosting provider where I manage my DNS zone file.

**Is it possible to configure my domain names with the multi-level subdomains?** Or, am I stuck with naming conventions like, `blog-stage.example.com`? Or, perhaps there is a better way to manage this that I don't know about?

**If it is possible, what would the DNS zone file look like?**

**And finally, if it is possible, what would the Nginx configuration file look like?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer comes from @sysadmin1138 and @cjc:

**Nginx Configuration**

Your nginx virt hosts will look something like this:

```
server {
  listen 1.1.1.1:80;
  server_name blog.stage.example.com;

[...]

}

server {
  listen 2.2.2.2:80;
  server_name blog.example.com;

[...]

}
```

This assumes that you can assign two IP addresses to your web server. With the above configuration, one virtual server will bind to 1.1.1.1:80 and respond to blog.stage.example.com, and the other server will bind to 2.2.2.2:80 and respond to blog.example.com. Setting up the DNS will depend on how your DNS is managed, but it should be do-able.

**DNS**

Sub-domains and hosting are a bit of an undefined, and you're best served asking them if they support something like that. It is quite possible to define an A record with multiple labels in it. For instance, you could put this in your DNS zone for example.com:

```
blog.stage             1.1.1.2
      blog             1.1.1.1
```

And it might work. Bind DNS does support that kind of thing, but whether or not your hosting provider lets you do that is another story entirely.

A better plan is to use something besides blog.

```
betablog              1.1.1.2
    blog              1.1.1.1
```

Since that's much more likely to be supported by your provider.

I'm not famililar enough with Nginx to provide multiple virtual-host examples for that.

Answer (score 3):

Your nginx virt hosts will look something like this:

```
server {
  listen 1.1.1.1:80;
  server_name blog.stage.example.com;

[...]

}

server {
  listen 2.2.2.2:80;
  server_name blog.example.com;

[...]

}
```

This assumes that you can assign two IP addresses to your web server.  With the above configuration, one virtual server will bind to 1.1.1.1:80 and respond to blog.stage.example.com, and the other server will bind to 2.2.2.2:80 and respond to blog.example.com.  Setting up the DNS will depend on how your DNS is managed, but it should be do-able.

Answer (score 2):

Sub-domains and hosting are a bit of an undefined, and you're best served asking them if they support something like that. It is quite possible to define an A record with multiple labels in it. For instance, you could put this in your DNS zone for example.com:

```
blog.stage             1.1.1.2
      blog             1.1.1.1
```

And it might work. Bind DNS does support that kind of thing, but whether or not your hosting provider lets you do that is another story entirely.

A better plan is to use something besides blog.

```
betablog              1.1.1.2
    blog              1.1.1.1
```

Since that's much more likely to be supported by your provider.

I'm not famililar enough with Nginx to provide multiple virtual-host examples for that.